# tmux force kill session (non graceful)

Tags: java, tmux

I'm running number of java services in linux via tmux sessions
each service has its own session.

To kill a service i use this

```
tmux kill-session -t $servicename
```

Some services (java) go nuts when attempting to kill them gracefully.
I believe this sends a signal that allows application to shut down gracefully.

**Is there a way to send a similar command via tmux or to tmux such that application  is terminated ungracefully?**